# Perl merging columns and adding new columns from different text files

Tags: perl, merge

I am a beginner with Perl and I want to merge and add new column the content of different text files.

My 1st file have two column.

```
chr1    14548  
chr1    15240272  
chr1    68723  
chr1    80040  
chr1    29627919  
chr1    63585628   
chr1    177110  
chr1    199016  
chr1    63600119
```

The 2nd file have one column

```
chr1    15240272  
chr1    29627919  
chr1    63585628  
chr1    63600119  
chr1    63608794  
chr1    63620650  
chr1    65986172  
chr1    81620996  
chr1    89015871  
chr1    96384184
```

The 3nd file have one column

```
chr1    3014448   
chr1    3068620  
chr1    3079928  
chr1    3082514  
chr1    3176980   
chr1    3198886  
chr1    3212349  
chr1    3249189  
chr1    3265742  
chr1    3273096
```

I want my output have 4 columns.

```
chr1    14548   chr1    3014448  
chr1    15240272   0    0  
chr1    68723   chr1    3068620  
chr1    80040   chr1    3079928  
chr1    29627919   0    0  
chr1    82626   chr1    3082514  
chr1    63585628   0    0  
chr1    177110  chr1    3176980  
chr1    199016  chr1    3198886  
chr1    212740  chr1    3212349
```

if the column1 in 2nd file, add 0 value in the column 2 and 3 of output file. else merge the column from file1 and 3 line by line. ( `chr1 14548 = chr1 3014448; chr1 68723 = chr1 3068620`, they all depending the sequence order, if I sort the column, it's impossible to identify `chr1 14548 = what`)

my Perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $input1, '<', "file1.txt"
    or die $!;
open my $input2, '<', "file2.txt"
    or die $!;
open my $input3, '<', "file3.txt"
    or die $!;
open my $outfile, '>', "output.txt"
    or die $!;
while ( my $l1 = <$input1> ) {
  my $l2 = <$input2>;
  my $l3 = <$input3>;
  chomp $l1;
  chomp $l2;
  chomp $l3;

  my @columns1 = split( /\t/, $l1 );
  my @columns2 = split( /\t/, $l2 );
  my @columns3 = split( /\t/, $l3 );
  if ( $columns2[1] == $columns1[1] ) {
    print $outfile join( "\t", $columns1[0], $columns1[1], '0', '0' ), "\n";
  }
  else {
    print $outfile
        join( "\t", $columns1[0], $columns1[1], $columns3[0], $columns3[1] ),
        "\n";
  }
}
close;
```

My Perl script can not work very well. Can't add 0 value in the output.

If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The first obvious problem is `if ($columns1[1]=$columns3[1])`. Use `==` for comparing numbers; `=` means assignment.

Comment: Another problem is the logic in your code doesn't match your description. You compare columns in file1 and file3 first, do something if they're the same, compare columns in file1 and file2, do something if they're the same, else do something else. Your description only talks about the latter two cases... which version is proper?

Comment: Your code always consumes one line from each file at every step, no matter which columns are equal.

Comment: yes, I found out my code did not do the match stuff. Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: I find myself unable to help, as I do not understand the desired output at all.
Numbers are just disappearing, what do you mean by "merge" ?
Any assumption I test on the data, I easily find a counter example,
like the second line with 0 0. Can you please make clear what you are trying to achieve, exactly? That might help you code as well

Comment: the output have 4 columns. chr1 14548 chr1 3014448 (chr1 14548 from file 1 and chr1 3014448 from file 3) depending on file 1, chr1 15240272 can be found in file 2. So the output will becaome (chr1 15240272 0 0)

Comment: if file 1 match with file 2, the output will add two more columns (0 values). otherwise, the list of file1 and file3 will combind together (chr1 68723 chr1 3068620; chr1 80040 chr1 3079928)

Comment: Did you write all of that code yourself? It looks like some of it was copied together from other places. I can tell because it's not indented, because the reading file handles have error messages that say _writing_, the `qq{}` operator that doesn't visually match the rest of the code and the stray `close`. It would help you if you understood what your code is doing, and why. It would help us to be able to read your code. I will indent it for you, so you can see how that makes it easier to understand. Next time, please do so yourself. Thanks.

Comment: I still get the error message about my code; "Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at Perl_file.pl line 24, <$input3> line 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it... Though I have no idea of the application.

The main change is that you need to read files 2 and 3 as required to line everything up.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $input1, '<', "file1.txt" or die $!;
open my $input2, '<', "file2.txt" or die $!;
open my $input3, '<', "file3.txt" or die $!;
open my $outfile, '>', "output.txt" or die $!;

my $line2 = <$input2>;
chomp($line2);
my @columns2 = split(/\t/, $line2);

while ( my $line1 = <$input1> ) {
    chomp($line1);
    my @columns1 = split(/\t/, $line1);

    if (@columns1[1] eq @columns2[1]) {
        # Line from input 1 matches line from input 2
        # Prep for next match and output zeros

        $line2 = <$input2>;
        chomp($line2);
        @columns2 = split(/\t/, $line2);

        print($outfile join("\t", @columns1, 0, 0), "\n");
    } else {
        # Input 1 does not match input 2
        # Read input 3 and print
        my $line3 = <$input3>;
        print($outfile  $line2, "\t", $line3);
    }
}
# Script ends, file handles are automatically closed
```

Comment: Thank you for your script. But I get all new columns were 0 ,0. And how come I still have error message about eq or (==) "Use of uninitialized value in string eq at Perl_file.pl line 18, <$input1> line 9"

Comment: if (@columns1[1] eq @columns2[2]) The script looks like if columns1 match column2, but they still only print out the ALL the columns1 with 2 new 0 valunes

Comment: Slight issue in my code, was comparing the third column from @columns2... which didn't exist. I've adjusted line 18.